# datepicker beforeShowDay return 3 months

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to disable some day in jquery datepicker calendar, so in the function beforeShowDay I write this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
            if(parseInt(calMonth) != parseInt(date.getMonth())){
                calMonth = date.getMonth();
                alert(calMonth + ' - ' + date.getMonth());
            }
            return {0: true};
        }
```

where calMonth contains the current month number. Now if I run this, I get 3 alert that show in order:
9-9, than 10-10 and than 11-11. Why I have 3 message, while it shouldn't show me anything (because when I open datepicker it shows by default the calendar of current month, so if(parseInt(calMonth) != parseInt(date.getMonth())) should return false.
I also set numberOfMonths: 1.

Comment: Do you enable the `showOtherMonths` option? That will show a few days from other months. Also, your function changes `calMonth`, so it's not always the current month.

Comment: I set showOtherMonths to false, but I still get 3 alerts. Yes I change calMonth, because I need to do an ajax call only one time when month is changed, so if I don't set calMonth to the current month that calendar shows, it would do 31 ajax call.

Comment: Now i saw that there is a option called onChangeMonthYear, maybe this one is the right one to use in this case. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, this is how i fixed:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ showWeek: true, showOtherMonths : false,
    //I'm using onChangeMonthYear to always keep my datepicker month updated
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
        $(this).datepicker( "setDate", month + '/1/' + year );
    },
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        //Now I can get only the days of the current selected month, and do whatever I want...
        if(date.getMonth()==$(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth()) 
            console.log(date.getDate()+' - '+date.getMonth()+' - '+$(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth());

        //keep returning as usual to the datepicker
        return [true, ''];
    } 
});
```

Hope it helps =)